# How to enforce no spaces in a bash script `read`?

Tags: bash

This is my function in a bash script

```
function add_github_token_with_alias(){

  while [ -z $alias ]
  do
    echo -en "\n"
    read -p "An alias to name your token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): " alias
  done

  while [ -z $token ]
  do
    echo -en "\n"
    read -p  "Token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): " token
  done
}
```

When I run it, it looks like this

```
An alias to name your token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): a new one
/opt/digitalocean/github_tokens_setup.sh: line 18: [: too many arguments

Token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): abc

Is the information correct? [Y/n]
```

Is there a way I can block user from submitting spaces in their response? How should I write it?

Comment: You can't prevent the user from adding spaces, but you can check the input and abort with an error message if they do.  Or you can massage the data and change it.  Or you can use quotes `while [ -z "$token" ]`

Comment: Ok thank you @WilliamPursell I know what to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for @WilliamPursell comment, I know what to do

I added

```
if [[ "$alias" =~ \  ]]; then
      echo "No spaces allowed!" >&2
      unset alias
fi
```

To do the checking of input as well as "$alias" in the while statement as per advised

```
function add_github_token_with_alias(){

  while [ -z "$alias" ]
  do
    echo "\n"
    read -p "An alias to name your token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): " alias
    if [[ "$alias" =~ \  ]]; then
      echo "No spaces allowed!" >&2
      unset alias
    fi
  done

  while [ -z "$token" ]
  do
    echo "\n"
    read -p  "Token (or press Ctrl+C to cancel): " token
    if [[ "$token" =~ \  ]]; then
      echo "No spaces allowed!" >&2
      unset token
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: Strongly recommend that you write error messages to stderr: `echo "No spaces allowed!" >&2`

Comment: Added as per your advice, @WilliamPursell

Comment: Be careful with that.  If you use 2 echos for the message and each go to a different stream, your output will be unexpected.  You could do `if ...; then echo  ...; echo ...; fi >&2` and write the output of everything in the `if` clause to stderr, but it is probably cleaner to use just one `echo`.

Comment: I rewrote it. Is that better now?

Comment: Yes, but be careful with `echo`.  It is not well standardized and you'll encounter some where `-en` does not do what you expect.  It seems odd to use any flags here.

Comment: Removed the flags as recommended